# How to compare return True or False if current ema matches with an ema 2 timeframes up ( only 1->15 and 5->30 )

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am looking to get a trend confirmation but the code seems to return values that are not being mapped in the correct place, at some of the buy and sell signals it works, on others not. Looking to see if I'm not getting the ema comparison correctly or what I might try differently.

The location of the trianges seem odd as well, could be part of the issue.

Edit : Results wanted ->

Green Arrow : Both 20 and 50 ema are in uptrend on (1 and 15 min) and (5 and 30 min) , regardless of fresh cross or inbetween run , only 1 call per uptrend and downtrend.

Red: Same as above but downtrend

```
//@version=5

indicator("Buy and Sell Signals Based off Trend matching ema from current and 2 time levels up", overlay = true)
s20_ema = ta.ema(close, 20) 
s50ema = ta.ema(close, 50)
s238ema = ta.ema(close,238)

Time = timeframe.period == "1" ? "15" : "30"
Current_Trend_Up = ta.ema(close, 20) > ta.ema(close, 50)
Current_Trend_Down = ta.ema(close, 20) < ta.ema(close, 50)
Two_Time_Frame_Ahead_Uptrend = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Time, ta.ema(close, 20) > ta.ema(close, 50), barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
Two_Time_Frame_Ahead_Downtrend = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Time, ta.ema(close, 20) < ta.ema(close, 50), barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)

Matching_Up_Trend = Current_Trend_Up and  Two_Time_Frame_Ahead_Uptrend ? true : false 
Matching_Down_Trend = Current_Trend_Down  and Two_Time_Frame_Ahead_Downtrend ? true : false 

Matching_Up_Trend_fixed = Matching_Up_Trend and not Matching_Up_Trend[1]
Matching_Down_Trend_fixed = Matching_Down_Trend and not Matching_Down_Trend[1]

plotshape(
 series    = Matching_Up_Trend_fixed,
 title     ='Buy', 
 style     = shape.triangleup, 
 location  = location.abovebar, 
 color     = color.new(color.blue, 0), 
 textcolor = color.new(color.white, 0), 
 text      = 'Buy', 
 size      = size.small)


plotshape(
 series    = Matching_Down_Trend_fixed,
 title     = 'Sell',
 style     = shape.triangledown, 
 location  = location.abovebar, 
 color     = color.new(color.red, 0), 
 textcolor = color.new(color.white, 0), 
 text      = 'Sell', 
 size      = size.small)
```

I tried a boolean return from comparing current ema with a higher timefram ema, using the security function. Tried to hardcode the time as well as some variations and searching for inbuilt solutions, but currently stuck.

I believe it is not matching the timeframes correctly, as I need 1 min with 15 and 5 with 30.

Comment: Can you explain the result your are looking for ?

Comment: Results wanted -> 

Green Arrow : Both 20 and 50 ema are in uptrend on (1 and 15 min) and (5 and 30 min) , regardless of fresh cross or inbetween run , only 1 call per uptrend and downtrend. 

Red: Same as above but downtrend

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly here is a working code for it. I made a few small changes to your code above

```
//@version=5

indicator("Buy and Sell Signals Based off Trend matching ema from current and 2 time levels up", overlay = true)
s20_ema = ta.ema(close, 20) 
s50ema = ta.ema(close, 50)
s238ema = ta.ema(close,238)

Time = timeframe.period == "1" ? "15" : "30"
Current_Trend_Up = s20_ema > s50ema
Current_Trend_Down = s20_ema < s50ema
Two_Ahead_20 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Time, s20_ema)
Two_Ahead_50 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Time, s50ema)
Two_Ahead_Uptrend = Two_Ahead_20 > Two_Ahead_50
Two_Ahead_Downtrend = Two_Ahead_20 < Two_Ahead_50

Matching_Up_Trend = Current_Trend_Up and Two_Ahead_Uptrend
Matching_Down_Trend = Current_Trend_Down and Two_Ahead_Downtrend

Matching_Up_Trend_fixed = Matching_Up_Trend and not Matching_Up_Trend[1]
Matching_Down_Trend_fixed = Matching_Down_Trend and not Matching_Down_Trend[1]

plotshape(
 series    = Matching_Up_Trend_fixed,
 title     ='Buy', 
 style     = shape.triangleup, 
 location  = location.abovebar, 
 color     = color.new(color.blue, 0), 
 textcolor = color.new(color.white, 0), 
 text      = 'Buy', 
 size      = size.small)


plotshape(
 series    = Matching_Down_Trend_fixed,
 title     = 'Sell',
 style     = shape.triangledown, 
 location  = location.abovebar, 
 color     = color.new(color.red, 0), 
 textcolor = color.new(color.white, 0), 
 text      = 'Sell', 
 size      = size.small)
```